# Prepositional phrase or adjective phrase

Tags: adverbs, nouns, clauses, adverbials

> i think that we can make a step in the right direction

In the sentence above, is "that we can make a step in the right direction" a noun clause or adverb clause?
It's very confusing for me to tell which is which.

Comment: We nearly always [***take** a step in the right direction*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+a+step+in+the%2Cmake+a+step+in+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) ***Making*** steps isn't common, but some of us do idiomatically ***make tracks*** when leaving.

Answer (score 2):

> *I think* [*that we can make a step in the right direction*].

The bracketed expression is a declarative content clause functioning as complement of "think".

I would advise you to drop the terms 'adverb clause' and 'noun clause'. The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.